# Why would a ring magnet's flux decrease once distance starts getting small?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I went ahead and use python magpylib to simulate a ring magnet joystick, and then graph flux over distance of the ring magnet. Here's the code:

```
from magpylib.source.magnet import Cylinder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import magpylib as magpy

# system parameters
outerDiameter, innerDiameter, height = 6.35, 3.175, 1.5875  # magnet dimension
M0 = 1320  # magnet magnetization amplitude
gap = 2.06  # airgap
distanceMagToTilt = 27.1  # distance magnet to center of tilt
thMAX = 25  # maximal joystick tilt angle
numIntervals = thMAX * 2  # the number of intervals to take for angle values tested.

distanceFluxAngleRecord = []

sensorPosition = np.asarray([0, 6.5, 0])

# set tilt angle
for theta in np.linspace(0, thMAX, numIntervals):

    # create ring magnet for joystick in center position, which is a cylinder magnet minus another cylinder magnet
    positiveMagnet = Cylinder(dim=[outerDiameter, height], mag=[0, 0,  M0], pos=[0, 0, height / 2 + gap])
    negativeMagnet = Cylinder(dim=[innerDiameter, height], mag=[0, 0, -M0], pos=[0, 0, height / 2 + gap])
    ringMagnet = magpy.Collection(positiveMagnet, negativeMagnet)

    # set joystick tilt th, at axis [0, 1, 0], anchored at point of rotation
    ringMagnet.rotate(theta, [0, 1, 0], anchor=[0, 0, gap + height + distanceMagToTilt])

    # rotate joystick for fixed tilt
    for i in range(360):
        fluxVector = ringMagnet.getB(sensorPosition)

        # either positive or negative magnet's position is the same thing as the ring magnet's position.
        physicalDistance = np.linalg.norm(ringMagnet.sources[0].position - sensorPosition)

        fluxMagnitude = np.linalg.norm(fluxVector)

        distanceFluxAngleRecord.append((physicalDistance, fluxMagnitude, theta))

        # rotate magnet to next position in the circle
        ringMagnet.rotate(1, [0, 0, 1], anchor=[0, 0, gap + height + distanceMagToTilt])

distanceFluxAngleRecord = np.asarray(distanceFluxAngleRecord)

x = distanceFluxAngleRecord[:, 0]
y = distanceFluxAngleRecord[:, 1]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel('distance [mm]')
plt.ylabel('flux magnitude [mT]')

plt.show()
```

Now, this is the image that got output, which doesn't make sense to me:

[image: flux vs distance of ring magnet]

It doesn't make sense because as the distance to the ring magnet gets smaller, at a certain point, the flux is going *down*, when I imagined that it should continue going *up*

I thought at first, since the angle of the magnet was changing, that maybe that was causing the flux to dip, since flux is equal to $|\mathbf B||\mathbf A|\cos(\theta)$. But then I decided to just change the line `ringMagnet = magpy.Collection(positiveMagnet, negativeMagnet)` to `ringMagnet = magpy.Collection(positiveMagnet)`, so that instead of a ring magnet, it's a plain cylindrical magnet. Making that change and rerunning the code, I get a graph which looks like this: A monotonically increasing flux as the magnet gets closer.

[image]

So from this, the change in angle isn't the thing causing flux to decrease as distance goes down. It's the fact that it's a ring magnet. Why would that be the case? why would flux *decrease* as you get very close to a ring magnet?

Comment: How big is the ring magnet?

Comment: outerDiameter =6.35 mm, innerDiameter = 3.175 mm, height = 1.5875 mm, and the remanence is 1320 mT

Comment: The field in the middle of the ring is weaker than the field very close to the ring itself. Your data supports this.

Comment: probably_someone, that must be what it is. Would you like to put that as an answer? If so I can upvote it and mark it as the answer to this question